# Is anyone able to identify this vintage aircraft please?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I have this plane on an art glass print in my home.  A lot of people ask what the plane is and I have been unable to identify it.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be a [Spartan 7W Executive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartan_Executive).

Comment: I think the risk of Wikipedia vanishing is pretty low risk. What would be useful here would be a list of the key features (eg. two blade prop, gear configuration, cabin structure, exhaust ports, etc) that might have informed this conclusion.

Comment: Yes, it is unmistakingly a Spartan Executive.

Answer (score 3):

As posted above, it is a Spartan Executive - the ultimate luxury airplane for the discerning private aviator in the late 1930s. They were a good size and very fast - the Gulfstream of their day, and as aspirational as a Lamborghini is to today's kids.
Quite a few are still flying, and I have seen several.
Here is a decent air-air photo of one, showing off its lines.
[image: Spartan Executive in flight]

Comment: It is considered good form to cite the source of posted photos.  Would you please add a link?

Comment: No original link available, sorry, it came from a recovered hard drive stripped of info, and is probably old enough to predate the internet archive.